# Would this be a suitable MVC chess (GUI) model?

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller, chess

I'm making a Java chess game as a uni project, and I'm basically getting the move from a player using a GUI.

My game has several classes, but the main classes are the Pieces, HumanPlayer and GraphicalDisplay classes.

What I'm basically doing is, when the HumanPlayer wants to make a move, it's currently using a class called PieceController, which is using a PieceModel class and the GraphicalDisplay classes as the model and view.

The problem is that I'm having to write code to set, for example, MouseListeners to certain cells in the chess grid (contained in an two dimensional array called cellHolder) in the Model class. This is because the code that contains adding listeners to cells also change state of the data, which is then used to display the game in the GUI.

This is causing a problem. The cellHolder object is created inside the GraphicalDisplay (GUI) class, but it's also used in the model and therefore the model is using data from the view.

I can't really think of another way of doing this without having to share (or pass as an argument) the cellHolder.

Any suggestions on how to improve the current MVC design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/adapter_pattern.htm

About Design Patterns In Java this one is called "the Adapter Pattern" .. It's basically a software design pattern that allows the interface of an existing class to be used from another interface

Comment: Thansk! I always see people saying that the MVC model is a bit out dated, however before that article I hadn't found something that could replace (or add functionality) to the MVC pattern.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid, but are you suggesting replacing my current MVC design with the adapter design or using them together?

Comment: you don't have to replace all your design of course :D .. you are just trying to understand the concept and then modifying your design to match with it